# Can you stay in the Schengen area for more than 90 days (not at once) with 2 year validity and multiple entry visa?

Tags: visa, schengen

My visa is valid for two years and is for multiple entries. The duration of stay says "90 days". Does this 90 day rule apply for every 180 days period in that two years validity OR is it a total of 90 days maximum for the entire two years?

In other words, can I do the following in one year?

```
Month 1-3   spend in schengen
Month 4-6   spend outside schengen
Month 7-9   spend in schengen
Month 10-12 spend outside schengen
```

Comment: @Mark Thank you so much. Is there any source of this? The duration of stay "90" days on my visa sticker is very confusing.

Comment: Is it a type D or type C visa?  What is the purpose of your travel, what is your destination, and which country issued the visa?  You have created two accounts, but you can [merge them](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @phoog It is type C to visit family. Its for all Schengen states

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stay 90 days in any 180-day period within the Schengen area.

| Period | Text |
| --- | --- |
| Day 1-90 | spend in schengen |
| Day 91-181 | spend outside schengen |
| Day 182-272 | spend in schengen |
| Day 273-363 | spend outside schengen |

The day of entry and the day of exit count as one full day.

The Schengen Border Code Article 1(1) ends with: 'not exceeding 90 days in any 180-day period.'

A visa can be restricted to a lesser amount of days that would match the dates in the FROM / UNTIL fields.

> [Schengen Visa Code, Annex VII](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A02009R0810-20160412#tocId82)
> **4.‘DURATION OF VISIT ... DAYS’ heading:**
> ...
> The maximum number of days that may be entered under this heading is 90.
>
> When a visa is valid for more than six months, the duration of stays is 90 days in any 180-day period.
> ...

Comment: This answer assumes that it is a type C visa, which it might not be.

Comment: @phoog A national visa (type D) for 90 days is actually very unlikely and even then the 90/180 day rule would apply outside the country that issued it. As far as I recall, a national visa can also be issued only up to 12 months.

Comment: Yes the visa is type C. I wonder why don't they write more than 90 days on the sticker then? It is confusing to write 90 days there when in reality its 90 in any 180 day period.

Comment: @Robin they don't put a higher number than 90 on the visa because then you might think that you could make a single visit of longer than 90 days, which isn't the case.  The rule is indeed complicated.  As a question about a short-term visit visa, this really belongs on [Travel.SE], where you will find a number of related questions including [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13183/19400)

Comment: @Robin This visa sticker is used for all types of different visas. The meaning of each field (and possible combinations) is defined in Annex VII of the Visa Code.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys